# Optimize conversion to decimal representation

Tags: python, optimization, decimal

I have a time which starts out represented by two integers: `t_sec` (number of seconds) and `t_nsec` (number of nanoseconds).  `t_nsec` is never more than 999999999 (it's always a fraction of a second).

I want to end up with a single numeric representation, always to 9 decimal places of precision.  I am using the Decimal class, however, any numeric floating point representation will work.

Example: `t_sec` = 10, `t_nsec` = 143, then output should be `10.000000143`

Current solution (works fine, but slow):

```
try:
    fraction = Decimal(t_nsec/1e9)
    answer = Decimal(t_sec) + fraction
    answer = answer.quantize(Decimal('0.000000001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
    return answer
except:
    ... error handling ...
```

Question: is there a faster way?  This is currently a bottleneck in one of my programs as it's called so many times.  The main offender is Decimal **add**, followed by Decimal **new**.

Comment: Do you need the precision of `Decimal()` at all? Using floating point would be far faster: `answer = t_sec + (t_nsec / 10**9)`. And since `t_nsec` is an integer to begin with, you don't need to use quantize at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any floating point representation would do, then stick to floating point. FP arithmetic is handled in hardware:

```
answer = t_sec + (t_nsec / 10**9)
```

You already killed your precision by using `t_nsec/1e9`, producing a float. If you are using Python 2 and are not using `from __future__ import division` you'll need to make one of the division operands a float:

```
answer = t_sec + (float(t_nsec) / 10**9)
```

Comment: Thanks, the routine is not even making the cutoff in the the profiling summary now.  :)   Should be `float(t_sec)` and `float(t_nsec)` because they start as `int`.

Comment: @Pete, the floats will be converted to double anyway, it is better to avoid two conversions. And also better to multiply by 0.000000001 instead of dividing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust this is *Python*, not C or Java, there is no double type here (although the float type is typically implemented using a double underneath). In Python 2 the division operator, given two integers, returns another integer hence the trick with turning `t_nsec` into a float first. But there is indeed no need to do this to `tsec` as the summing with another float takes care of that here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's just a bit of cheating:

```
answer = Decimal('{}.{:09}'.format(t_sec, t_nsec))
```

Comment: As Martijn pointed out I don't even need Decimal, but, this certainly is much better than what I had and reduces the calls to `new`.